# Struggling with passing String from Client to Server

Tags: javafx, server, stream, client

looking for some help! I've been trying to get this to work for way too long now. I originally  tried having the Server and the JavaFX Part of it (The actual Stage, start method etc) inside of the same Class, but after hours of trying I went ahead and seperated those to try from scratch. Sadly no luck.

Heres my Server:

```
public class Server
{
    String s = "";
   public void startServer() throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket (8896);
        while(true)
        {
                    Socket socket = null;
                    try
                    {
                            socket = server.accept();
                            System.out.println("Connected");
                            BufferedReader dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                            s = dis.readLine();
                            System.out.println(dis.readLine());
                    }
                    catch(IOException e){}
                    finally
                    {
                        if(socket != null)
                            try
                            {
                                    socket.close();
                            }
                            catch(IOException e){}
                    }
            }
    }
    public  String giveString()
    {
        return s;
    }
}
```

My Client:

```
public class Client
{
    private String string = "";
    private Socket s;

    public void connect() throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        s = new Socket("localhost",8896);
        PrintStream dos = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream(),true);
        dos.println(string);
        dos.flush();
        s.close();   
    }

    public void setString(String string)
    {
        this.string = string;
    }
}
```

And lastly, my ServerGUI class. I want to show the String *s* beeing passed through Client->Server.giveString()->ServerGUI in the TextField I added to the Scene.

```
public class ServerGUI extends Application
{
    private TextField tf = new TextField("");
    private static Server server = new Server();
    private SimpleStringProperty ssp = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public void initialize() throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {


        ssp.bind(tf.textProperty());
        tf.textProperty().set(server.giveString());
        ssp.setValue(server.giveString());
        server.startServer();
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 380, 200);
        root.getChildren().add(tf);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        server.startServer();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {

        launch(args);
    }

}
```

I tried putting the server.startServer(); in different positions in ServerGUI  already, with different results. Never found a solution. Im sure this is very simple, I would be very thankful if someone could give me some pointers. Im just not making any progress at all and I feel like I tried every single Idea I had here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your server class has a call to `accept()`. Which waits for a client socket to be started. Your code never gets passed this point since the thread is just waiting there. You can look at the code I've posted below to see this is true. I have a `Thread.sleep(6000)` (6seconds) in the Thread that the client is created so you can see that the server never prints out "Connected" until it accepts a `Socket`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Test extends Application
{
    private Label tf = new Label("");
    private static Server server = new Server();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 380, 200);
        root.getChildren().add(tf);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        tf.textProperty().bind(server.passedStringValProperty());

        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                server.startServer();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, "Server socket listener").start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(6000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Client client = new Client();
            client.setString("Hello world!");
            try{
                client.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }, "Client connection").start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    private static class Server
    {

        public SimpleStringProperty passedStringValProperty () {
            return passedStringVal;
        }

        private SimpleStringProperty passedStringVal = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public void startServer () throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8896);

            // Removed while loop since you only need 1 instance
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                socket = server.accept();
                System.out.println("Connected");
                BufferedReader dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                final String passedVal = dis.readLine();

                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                            passedStringVal.set(passedVal);
                        });

                System.out.println(passedVal);
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            } finally {
                if (socket != null)
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException ignored) {
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Client{
        private String string = "";
        private Socket s;

        public void connect() throws IOException
        {
            s = new Socket("localhost",8896);
            PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream(),true);
            stream.println(string);
            s.close();
        }

        public void setString(String string)
        {
            this.string = string;
        }
    }
}
```

You can separate the `Client` and `Server` into their own classes, I just left them as static classes to fit them into the main class. I also removed the `while(true)` loop from your code. The loop will only be necessary if you are wanting to keep checking sockets. The code in the server class will also hang at `readLine()` until the Client sends something (you can test this by putting a `Thread.sleep()` call in the client's connect function before the `stream.println()`.

So the reason you weren't able to get passed the server.startServer() was because it was running in the main thread and hanging everything.